# Ubuntu whoopsie offline, ethernet network goes off

Tags: networking, 20.04, network-manager, ethernet, 21.04

I have Ubuntu 21.04(Had same on 20.04). And randomly my internet disconnects for 1-5 seconds. When this happends I see this in logs.

```
14:08:18 whoopsie: [14:08:18] online
14:08:18 whoopsie: [14:08:18] Found usable connection: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/1
14:08:18 whoopsie: [14:08:18] Not a paid data plan: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/1
14:08:18 whoopsie: [14:08:18] The default IPv4 route is: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/1
14:08:18 NetworkManager: <info>  [1629803298.4232] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_GLOBAL
14:08:18 systemd: Started Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service.
14:08:18 dbus-daemon: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher'
14:08:18 systemd: Starting Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service...
14:08:18 dbus-daemon: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.nm-dispatcher.service' requested by ':1.9' (uid=0 pid=703 comm="/usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon " label="unconfined")
14:08:18 whoopsie: [14:08:18] offline
14:08:18 NetworkManager: <info>  [1629803298.1533] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_SITE
```

I tried reinstalling linux-headers, updating all packages, and ubuntu itself, and upgraded ubuntu from 20.04 to 21.04. Can this also be my network problem and not linux? Because it is in logs and I dont understand whether it network manager problem or my internet problem

`sudo lshw -C network` results as someone requested:

```
  *-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
       logical name: enp4s0
       version: 15
       serial: b0:6e:bf:c8:0e:3f
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=5.11.0-31-generic duplex=full firmware=rtl8168h-2_0.0.2 02/26/15 ip=192.168.1.242 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:19 ioport:d000(size=256) memory:f7104000-f7104fff memory:f7100000-f7103fff
```

Also `ls -al /var/crash`

```
total 33376
drwxrwsrwt  2 root     whoopsie     4096 Aug 23 23:39 .
drwxr-xr-x 14 root     root         4096 Feb  9  2021 ..
-rw-r-----  1 root     whoopsie   714106 Aug 23 23:38 postfix.0.crash
-rw-r--r--  1 root     whoopsie        0 Aug 23 23:38 postfix.0.upload
-rw-------  1 whoopsie whoopsie       37 Aug 23 23:39 postfix.0.uploaded
-rw-r-----  1 vadim    whoopsie  2906719 Aug 23 23:25 _usr_libexec_tracker-extract.1000.crash
-rw-r-----  1 vadim    whoopsie 30538240 Aug 23 23:25 _usr_share_apport_apport-gtk.1000.crash
```

Comment: Whoopsie service does error reporting. Here from logs it looks like it is finding active connection to report error canonical but it is not error or issue.

Comment: @KKPatel , but when this happens internet goes off, and what NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_SITE means?

Comment: it is able to connect repoting site. Issue may be at network level. Did you face similar issue on another device in same network ?

Comment: I can't actually test on another device, but I will try to do something with my network, changing ethernet cable etc.

Comment: Look in your /var/crash directory for .crash files that were created within a minute or two of known internet outages. Those .crash files detail the *actual* problem that you are encountering. They are text files -- open them, look around. The `apport` application creates the .crash files; it is triggered when systemd detects an application crash. `whoopsie` is merely the tiny service that sends the completed .crash file to Canonical's `daisy` server; it is not the *cause* of crashes or network outages.

Comment: @user535733 , As I understood if I would have crash file here it is NetworkManager problem?

Comment: No. If you would have a crash file there, *the crash file will tell you the problem*.

Comment: Edit your question and show me `sudo lshw -C network` and `ls -al /var/crash`. Please describe your network wiring configuration.

Comment: @heynnema , I edited my question and added what you want

Comment: If you are having trouble understanding the .crash file, put the crashfile contents in any pastebin ([here's one](http://paste.ubuntu.com)) and prove the link to that pastebin.

Comment: Thanks for the update. However you forgot... Please describe your network wiring configuration. Homemade cables, or purchased?

Comment: @user535733 , I don't see Network Manager crashes at that logs

Comment: @heynnema , I don't quite understand what do you mean by wiring configuration

Comment: Describe the ethernet cabling from the port on the rear of the computer, all the way to your router/modem. Include hubs/switches/etc. I'm trying to determine if your problem is there. Are your cables homemade, or purchased new?

Comment: @heynnema , if it is hardware problem I think I should just inspect it by myself, like changing cables etc.

Comment: As far as I know, cables not new. And I think all connected to hub, from where routers go. As far as I remember.

Comment: Your answer was incomplete... so I can only guess... connect a new, pre-made, ethernet cable directly from the computer to your router/modem, and see if the problem is gone.